Is it possible to use a `for` loop without `if` statements
Here is my batch script. I process paired data arrays #DE and #ID within a for loop using if statements:
@echo off
fltmc.exe >nul || (sudo.exe "%~0"&& exit /b)
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%b in ('
bcdedit.exe /enum osloader^|findstr.exe "den des"') do (
    if defined #LN (
        set /a #n+=1
        set #DE[!#n!]=%%b %%c
        set #ID[!#n!]=!#LN!
        set #LN=
    ) else (
        set #LN=%%b
    )
)
(for %%a in (#DE #ID) do set %%a)& pause

I am trying to find a way to achieve this without using if statements, as I believe it would be faster. However, it seems that I haven't found a solution yet, or perhaps there isn't one.
What I mean by doing it without if is similar to the following example in PowerShell:
function WData {
    $kws  = 'identifier|description'
    $data = (bcdedit.exe /enum osloader | 
        sls $kws).Line.TrimStart($kws).Trim()
    for ($n=0; $n -lt $data.count; $n +=2) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            de  = $data[$n+1]
            id  = $data[$n]
        }
    }
}


What stops you from just using powershell?

I presume that each call to bcdedit and then piping to findstr is an order of magnitude slower than a single if defined per loop, so I wonder if you are correct about conditionals making a meaningful impact on the speed. Each call to a system utility is an OS scheduling operation. You might actually gain more speed by using the full paths to findstr and bcdedit rather than eliminating a single IF

@LPChip If what you mean is calling PowerShell from a batch file, it's a bad idea if I'm looking for speed.

@Yorik If using findstr.exe actually slows down the process, that's something I hadn't considered. It's a good idea. I will try an alternative method without it and then compare the speed between the two. Thank you

No, I mean, write your entire script in powershell. All batch commands work in powershell, and the internal batch commands will have a powershell counterpart. But given that powershell is much more developed, and you can do so much more with powershell, its likely going to be a lot faster too.

This is the command in powershell btw: (bcdedit /enum osloader | where {$_ -match "de[ns]"}|measure).count/2

@LPChip For learning motivation, I sometimes create scripts for the same function in different PL. For this, I have already made it in .ps1, .bat, .py, .go, .cs. and I have found that I struggle to avoid 'if' statements in 'for' loops only in CMD.

well, that is not surprising. CMD isn't really a scripting language. It is a command based interpreter, and although it can often get the job done, its not elegant, and things like if are really necessary in some cases. The reason people choose cmd over any other language, is because it exists on every windows machine and is very easy to learn. Powershell too exists on every machine now, but is a lot harder to learn because it has a more programming oriented language with integration of .net.

I think that using the full paths to both in the call saves the OS time in tracking down each executable in PATH. That is per loop so it can become significant if there are very many iterations.
